# Why is my setter method not getting called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this in my .h file: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *valoresTotaisNutricao;`

And then, I override setter and getter like this:

```
-(void)setValoresTotaisNutricao:(NSMutableDictionary *)valoresTotaisNutricao
{
    NSLog(@"setter");
    [self oDicionarioEdeHoje];
    if ([self oDicionarioEdeHoje] == NO) {
        // Data não está atualizada, apagar dicionário e setar nova.
        [_valoresTotaisNutricao removeAllObjects];
        [_valoresTotaisNutricao setObject:[self pegarFinalDoDia] forKey:@"data"];
    }
    _valoresTotaisNutricao = valoresTotaisNutricao;
}

-(NSMutableDictionary *)valoresTotaisNutricao
{
    NSLog(@"getter");
    if (!_valoresTotaisNutricao) {
        _valoresTotaisNutricao = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[self pegarFinalDoDia], @"data", nil];
    }
    return _valoresTotaisNutricao;
}
```

And I use `@synthesize valoresTotaisNutricao = _valoresTotaisNutricao;`.

My `getter` works, but my `setter` never gets called. I tried to explicit declare the method name on the `@property` declaration but it didn't work as well.

UPDATE:

I try to add some values to the `NSMutableDictionary` from another class.

`[singleton.valoresTotaisNutricao setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:222] forKey:@"teste"];`.

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've posted do you call the setter method.

Comment: Post the code that you expect the setter should get called.

Comment: I call it from other class, using: `[singleton.valoresTotaisNutricao setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:222] forKey:@"teste"];`

Comment: That is not the setter method for your property.

Comment: You're confusing a method on NSDictionary that sets objects for keys with the setter for your NSDictionary instance.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I got it all wrong then... Let me ask differently then: I'm trying to populate my `NSMutableDictionary`, but I want one key to always be there, and according to some conditions, reset that key. How could I do this then? Thanks.

Comment: I understand what you are saying then. So basically, I think I need to override that particular method to set objects for keys, can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setObject:forKey:` does not call your setter method.

`singleton.valoresTotaisNutricao` will call your getter method, which you have lazily-loading your property, and then `setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:222] forKey:@"teste"` will set a value for the key of `@"teste"` on that dictionary, but nowhere in that code does your setter method get called.

You would need to use either this:

`singleton.valoresTotaisNutricao = <some mutable dictionary object>;`

or this:

`[singleton setValoresTotaisNutricao:<some mutable dictionary object>];`

... to call your setter method.

Comment: Got it. That should do it. So do I need to create another `dictionary` and pass it? I guess I will have to make a copy of that one, change it and pass it back? I thought I could custom write directly to that instance.

Comment: Yes, you would create another dictionary to pass into your setter method.

Comment: Wait, just to be clear, it's not *another* instance; it's the *first* instance. You have to initialize the property before it refers to anything.

Comment: Ah, wait, I missed that you were doing some sort of lazy-loading in the getter.